# Enabling CQL Binary Protocol throws YAMLException: Unable to find property - in DataStax 3.0 installation in ubuntu

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to connect to DataStax 3.0 enterprise installed in a Ubuntu desktop running inside a VM from a C# client (courtesy [CassandraSharp](https://github.com/pchalamet/cassandra-sharp/wiki/Having-troubles)).

As per the documentation there, (*"Cassandra does not enable CQL Binary Protocol by default (as of 1.2-rc2). You have to enable this feature in cassandra.yaml in order to use cassandra-sharp"*), I introduced this entry "start_native_transport: true" into cassandra.yaml and when I start the service from Ubuntu terminal, I get this error:

> INFO 02:57:53,734 Loading settings from file:/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
>   ERROR 02:57:55,834 Fatal configuration error error
>   Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=start_native_transport for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@7f636e4e; Unable to find property 'start_native_transport' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config

Any idea how to enable binary protocol in DataStax Cassandra? Or am I doing anything wrong? Is it location specific in the config file - I'm new to linux!!
The full yaml file here as asked:

```
# Cassandra storage config YAML 


# The name of the cluster. This is mainly used to prevent machines in
# one logical cluster from joining another.
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'

initial_token:

hinted_handoff_enabled: true

max_hint_window_in_ms: 3600000 # one hour

hinted_handoff_throttle_delay_in_ms: 1



# authentication backend, implementing IAuthenticator; used to identify users
authenticator: org.apache.cassandra.auth.AllowAllAuthenticator
#authenticator: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator
#authenticator: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.KerberosAuthenticator

# authorization backend, implementing IAuthorizer; used to limit access/provide permissions
authorizer: org.apache.cassandra.auth.AllowAllAuthorizer
#authorizer: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.CassandraAuthorizer

permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000

# Replication strategy to use for the auth keyspace.
auth_replication_strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy

# Replication options to use for the auth keyspace.
auth_replication_options:
    replication_factor: 1

# The partitioner is responsible for distributing rows (by key) across
# nodes in the cluster.  Any IPartitioner may be used, including your
# own as long as it is on the classpath.  Out of the box, Cassandra
# provides org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner
# org.apache.cassandra.dht.ByteOrderedPartitioner,
# org.apache.cassandra.dht.OrderPreservingPartitioner (deprecated),
# and org.apache.cassandra.dht.CollatingOrderPreservingPartitioner
# (deprecated).
# 
# - RandomPartitioner distributes rows across the cluster evenly by md5.
#   When in doubt, this is the best option.
# - ByteOrderedPartitioner orders rows lexically by key bytes.  BOP allows
#   scanning rows in key order, but the ordering can generate hot spots
#   for sequential insertion workloads.
# - OrderPreservingPartitioner is an obsolete form of BOP, that stores
# - keys in a less-efficient format and only works with keys that are
#   UTF8-encoded Strings.
# - CollatingOPP colates according to EN,US rules rather than lexical byte
#   ordering.  Use this as an example if you need custom collation.
#
# See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations for more on
# partitioners and token selection.
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner

# directories where Cassandra should store data on disk.
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data

# commit log
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog

# Maximum size of the key cache in memory.
#
# Each key cache hit saves 1 seek and each row cache hit saves 2 seeks at the
# minimum, sometimes more. The key cache is fairly tiny for the amount of
# time it saves, so it's worthwhile to use it at large numbers.
# The row cache saves even more time, but must store the whole values of
# its rows, so it is extremely space-intensive. It's best to only use the
# row cache if you have hot rows or static rows.
#
# NOTE: if you reduce the size, you may not get you hottest keys loaded on startup.
#
# Default value is empty to make it "auto" (min(5% of Heap (in MB), 100MB)). Set to 0 to disable key cache.
key_cache_size_in_mb:

# Duration in seconds after which Cassandra should
# safe the keys cache. Caches are saved to saved_caches_directory as
# specified in this configuration file.
#
# Saved caches greatly improve cold-start speeds, and is relatively cheap in
# terms of I/O for the key cache. Row cache saving is much more expensive and
# has limited use.
#
# Default is 14400 or 4 hours.
key_cache_save_period: 14400

# Number of keys from the key cache to save
# Disabled by default, meaning all keys are going to be saved
# key_cache_keys_to_save: 100

# Maximum size of the row cache in memory.
# NOTE: if you reduce the size, you may not get you hottest keys loaded on startup.
#
# Default value is 0, to disable row caching.
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0

# Duration in seconds after which Cassandra should
# safe the row cache. Caches are saved to saved_caches_directory as specified
# in this configuration file.
#
# Saved caches greatly improve cold-start speeds, and is relatively cheap in
# terms of I/O for the key cache. Row cache saving is much more expensive and
# has limited use.
#
# Default is 0 to disable saving the row cache.
row_cache_save_period: 0

# Number of keys from the row cache to save
# Disabled by default, meaning all keys are going to be saved
# row_cache_keys_to_save: 100

# The provider for the row cache to use.
#
# Supported values are: ConcurrentLinkedHashCacheProvider, SerializingCacheProvider
#
# SerializingCacheProvider serialises the contents of the row and stores
# it in native memory, i.e., off the JVM Heap. Serialized rows take
# significantly less memory than "live" rows in the JVM, so you can cache
# more rows in a given memory footprint.  And storing the cache off-heap
# means you can use smaller heap sizes, reducing the impact of GC pauses.
#
# It is also valid to specify the fully-qualified class name to a class
# that implements org.apache.cassandra.cache.IRowCacheProvider.
#
# Defaults to SerializingCacheProvider
row_cache_provider: SerializingCacheProvider

# saved caches
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches

# commitlog_sync may be either "periodic" or "batch." 
# When in batch mode, Cassandra won't ack writes until the commit log
# has been fsynced to disk.  It will wait up to
# commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms milliseconds for other writes, before
# performing the sync.
#
# commitlog_sync: batch
# commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms: 50
#
# the other option is "periodic" where writes may be acked immediately
# and the CommitLog is simply synced every commitlog_sync_period_in_ms
# milliseconds.
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

# The size of the individual commitlog file segments.  A commitlog
# segment may be archived, deleted, or recycled once all the data
# in it (potentally from each columnfamily in the system) has been 
# flushed to sstables.  
#
# The default size is 32, which is almost always fine, but if you are
# archiving commitlog segments (see commitlog_archiving.properties),
# then you probably want a finer granularity of archiving; 8 or 16 MB
# is reasonable.
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32

# any class that implements the SeedProvider interface and has a
# constructor that takes a Map<String, String> of parameters will do.
seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points. 
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1"

# emergency pressure valve: each time heap usage after a full (CMS)
# garbage collection is above this fraction of the max, Cassandra will
# flush the largest memtables.  
#
# Set to 1.0 to disable.  Setting this lower than
# CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction is not likely to be useful.
#
# RELYING ON THIS AS YOUR PRIMARY TUNING MECHANISM WILL WORK POORLY:
# it is most effective under light to moderate load, or read-heavy
# workloads; under truly massive write load, it will often be too
# little, too late.
flush_largest_memtables_at: 0.75

# emergency pressure valve #2: the first time heap usage after a full
# (CMS) garbage collection is above this fraction of the max,
# Cassandra will reduce cache maximum _capacity_ to the given fraction
# of the current _size_.  Should usually be set substantially above
# flush_largest_memtables_at, since that will have less long-term
# impact on the system.  
# 
# Set to 1.0 to disable.  Setting this lower than
# CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction is not likely to be useful.
reduce_cache_sizes_at: 0.85
reduce_cache_capacity_to: 0.6

# For workloads with more data than can fit in memory, Cassandra's
# bottleneck will be reads that need to fetch data from
# disk. "concurrent_reads" should be set to (16 * number_of_drives) in
# order to allow the operations to enqueue low enough in the stack
# that the OS and drives can reorder them.
#
# On the other hand, since writes are almost never IO bound, the ideal
# number of "concurrent_writes" is dependent on the number of cores in
# your system; (8 * number_of_cores) is a good rule of thumb.
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32

# Total memory to use for memtables.  Cassandra will flush the largest
# memtable when this much memory is used.
# If omitted, Cassandra will set it to 1/3 of the heap.
# memtable_total_space_in_mb: 2048

# Total space to use for commitlogs.  Since commitlog segments are
# mmapped, and hence use up address space, the default size is 32
# on 32-bit JVMs, and 1024 on 64-bit JVMs.
#
# If space gets above this value (it will round up to the next nearest
# segment multiple), Cassandra will flush every dirty CF in the oldest
# segment and remove it.  So a small total commitlog space will tend
# to cause more flush activity on less-active columnfamilies.
# commitlog_total_space_in_mb: 4096

# This sets the amount of memtable flush writer threads.  These will
# be blocked by disk io, and each one will hold a memtable in memory
# while blocked. If you have a large heap and many data directories,
# you can increase this value for better flush performance.
# By default this will be set to the amount of data directories defined.
#memtable_flush_writers: 1

# the number of full memtables to allow pending flush, that is,
# waiting for a writer thread.  At a minimum, this should be set to
# the maximum number of secondary indexes created on a single CF.
memtable_flush_queue_size: 4

# Whether to, when doing sequential writing, fsync() at intervals in
# order to force the operating system to flush the dirty
# buffers. Enable this to avoid sudden dirty buffer flushing from
# impacting read latencies. Almost always a good idea on SSD:s; not
# necessarily on platters.
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240

# TCP port, for commands and data
storage_port: 7000

# SSL port, for encrypted communication.  Unused unless enabled in
# encryption_options
ssl_storage_port: 7001

# Address to bind to and tell other Cassandra nodes to connect to. You
# _must_ change this if you want multiple nodes to be able to
# communicate!
# 
# Leaving it blank leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This
# will always do the Right Thing *if* the node is properly configured
# (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the
# address associated with the hostname (it might not be).
#
# Setting this to 0.0.0.0 is always wrong.
#listen_address: localhost -- commented by nachi 19Mar2013
listen_address: 192.168.42.236

# Address to broadcast to other Cassandra nodes
# Leaving this blank will set it to the same value as listen_address
# broadcast_address: 1.2.3.4

# The address to bind the Thrift RPC service to -- clients connect
# here. Unlike ListenAddress above, you *can* specify 0.0.0.0 here if
# you want Thrift to listen on all interfaces.
# 
# Leaving this blank has the same effect it does for ListenAddress,
# (i.e. it will be based on the configured hostname of the node).
#rpc_address: 0.0.0.0 -- commented by nachi on 19Mar2013
rpc_address: 192.168.42.236
# port for Thrift to listen for clients on
rpc_port: 9160

# enable or disable keepalive on rpc connections
rpc_keepalive: true

# Cassandra provides three options for the RPC Server:
#
# sync  -> One connection per thread in the rpc pool (see below).
#          For a very large number of clients, memory will be your limiting
#          factor; on a 64 bit JVM, 128KB is the minimum stack size per thread.
#          Connection pooling is very, very strongly recommended.
#
# async -> Nonblocking server implementation with one thread to serve 
#          rpc connections.  This is not recommended for high throughput use
#          cases. Async has been tested to be about 50% slower than sync
#          or hsha and is deprecated: it will be removed in the next major release.
#
# hsha  -> Stands for "half synchronous, half asynchronous." The rpc thread pool 
#          (see below) is used to manage requests, but the threads are multiplexed
#          across the different clients.
#
# The default is sync because on Windows hsha is about 30% slower.  On Linux,
# sync/hsha performance is about the same, with hsha of course using less memory.
rpc_server_type: sync

# Uncomment rpc_min|max|thread to set request pool size.
# You would primarily set max for the sync server to safeguard against
# misbehaved clients; if you do hit the max, Cassandra will block until one
# disconnects before accepting more.  The defaults for sync are min of 16 and max
# unlimited.
# 
# For the Hsha server, the min and max both default to quadruple the number of
# CPU cores.
#
# This configuration is ignored by the async server.
#
# rpc_min_threads: 16
# rpc_max_threads: 2048

# uncomment to set socket buffer sizes on rpc connections
# rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes:
# rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes:

# Frame size for thrift (maximum field length).
# 0 disables TFramedTransport in favor of TSocket. This option
# is deprecated; we strongly recommend using Framed mode.
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
start_native_transport: true
# added by nac to enable binary protocol that suppofrts async stuff


# The max length of a thrift message, including all fields and
# internal thrift overhead.
thrift_max_message_length_in_mb: 16

# Set to true to have Cassandra create a hard link to each sstable
# flushed or streamed locally in a backups/ subdirectory of the
# Keyspace data.  Removing these links is the operator's
# responsibility.
incremental_backups: false

# Whether or not to take a snapshot before each compaction.  Be
# careful using this option, since Cassandra won't clean up the
# snapshots for you.  Mostly useful if you're paranoid when there
# is a data format change.
snapshot_before_compaction: false

# Whether or not a snapshot is taken of the data before keyspace truncation
# or dropping of column families. The STRONGLY advised default of true 
# should be used to provide data safety. If you set this flag to false, you will
# lose data on truncation or drop.
auto_snapshot: true

# Add column indexes to a row after its contents reach this size.
# Increase if your column values are large, or if you have a very large
# number of columns.  The competing causes are, Cassandra has to
# deserialize this much of the row to read a single column, so you want
# it to be small - at least if you do many partial-row reads - but all
# the index data is read for each access, so you don't want to generate
# that wastefully either.
column_index_size_in_kb: 64

# Size limit for rows being compacted in memory.  Larger rows will spill
# over to disk and use a slower two-pass compaction process.  A message
# will be logged specifying the row key.
in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64

# Number of simultaneous compactions to allow, NOT including
# validation "compactions" for anti-entropy repair.  Simultaneous
# compactions can help preserve read performance in a mixed read/write
# workload, by mitigating the tendency of small sstables to accumulate
# during a single long running compactions. The default is usually
# fine and if you experience problems with compaction running too
# slowly or too fast, you should look at
# compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec first.
#
# This setting has no effect on LeveledCompactionStrategy.
#
# concurrent_compactors defaults to the number of cores.
# Uncomment to make compaction mono-threaded, the pre-0.8 default.
#concurrent_compactors: 1

# Multi-threaded compaction. When enabled, each compaction will use
# up to one thread per core, plus one thread per sstable being merged.
# This is usually only useful for SSD-based hardware: otherwise, 
# your concern is usually to get compaction to do LESS i/o (see:
# compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec), not more.
multithreaded_compaction: false

# Throttles compaction to the given total throughput across the entire
# system. The faster you insert data, the faster you need to compact in
# order to keep the sstable count down, but in general, setting this to
# 16 to 32 times the rate you are inserting data is more than sufficient.
# Setting this to 0 disables throttling. Note that this account for all types
# of compaction, including validation compaction.
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16

# Track cached row keys during compaction, and re-cache their new
# positions in the compacted sstable.  Disable if you use really large
# key caches.
compaction_preheat_key_cache: true

# Throttles all outbound streaming file transfers on this node to the
# given total throughput in Mbps. This is necessary because Cassandra does
# mostly sequential IO when streaming data during bootstrap or repair, which
# can lead to saturating the network connection and degrading rpc performance.
# When unset, the default is 400 Mbps or 50 MB/s.
# stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec: 400

# Time to wait for a reply from other nodes before failing the command 
rpc_timeout_in_ms: 10000

# Enable socket timeout for streaming operation.
# When a timeout occurs during streaming, streaming is retried from the start
# of the current file. This *can* involve re-streaming an important amount of
# data, so you should avoid setting the value too low.
# Default value is 0, which never timeout streams.
# streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms: 0

# phi value that must be reached for a host to be marked down.
# most users should never need to adjust this.
# phi_convict_threshold: 8

# endpoint_snitch -- Set this to a class that implements
# IEndpointSnitch.  The snitch has two functions:
# - it teaches Cassandra enough about your network topology to route
#   requests efficiently
# - it allows Cassandra to spread replicas around your cluster to avoid
#   correlated failures. It does this by grouping machines into
#   "datacenters" and "racks."  Cassandra will do its best not to have
#   more than one replica on the same "rack" (which may not actually
#   be a physical location)
#
# IF YOU CHANGE THE SNITCH AFTER DATA IS INSERTED INTO THE CLUSTER,
# YOU MUST RUN A FULL REPAIR, SINCE THE SNITCH AFFECTS WHERE REPLICAS
# ARE PLACED.
#
# Out of the box, Cassandra provides
#  - SimpleSnitch:
#    Treats Strategy order as proximity. This improves cache locality
#    when disabling read repair, which can further improve throughput.
#    Only appropriate for single-datacenter deployments.
#  - PropertyFileSnitch:
#    Proximity is determined by rack and data center, which are
#    explicitly configured in cassandra-topology.properties.
#  - GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
#    The rack and datacenter for the local node are defined in
#    cassandra-rackdc.properties and propagated to other nodes via gossip.  If
#    cassandra-topology.properties exists, it is used as a fallback, allowing
#    migration from the PropertyFileSnitch.
#  - RackInferringSnitch:
#    Proximity is determined by rack and data center, which are
#    assumed to correspond to the 3rd and 2nd octet of each node's
#    IP address, respectively.  Unless this happens to match your
#    deployment conventions (as it did Facebook's), this is best used
#    as an example of writing a custom Snitch class.
#  - Ec2Snitch:
#    Appropriate for EC2 deployments in a single Region.  Loads Region
#    and Availability Zone information from the EC2 API. The Region is
#    treated as the Datacenter, and the Availability Zone as the rack.
#    Only private IPs are used, so this will not work across multiple
#    Regions.
#  - Ec2MultiRegionSnitch:
#    Uses public IPs as broadcast_address to allow cross-region
#    connectivity.  (Thus, you should set seed addresses to the public
#    IP as well.) You will need to open the storage_port or
#    ssl_storage_port on the public IP firewall.  (For intra-Region
#    traffic, Cassandra will switch to the private IP after
#    establishing a connection.)
# DataStax Enterprise provides
#  - com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch:
#    Proximity is determined by the settings in dse.yaml:delegated_snitch to
#    allow DSE to add location aware functionality. This is required for DSE.
#
# You can use a custom Snitch by setting this to the full class name
# of the snitch, which will be assumed to be on your classpath.
endpoint_snitch: com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch

# controls how often to perform the more expensive part of host score
# calculation
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
# controls how often to reset all host scores, allowing a bad host to
# possibly recover
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
# if set greater than zero and read_repair_chance is < 1.0, this will allow
# 'pinning' of replicas to hosts in order to increase cache capacity.
# The badness threshold will control how much worse the pinned host has to be
# before the dynamic snitch will prefer other replicas over it.  This is
# expressed as a double which represents a percentage.  Thus, a value of
# 0.2 means Cassandra would continue to prefer the static snitch values
# until the pinned host was 20% worse than the fastest.
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1

# request_scheduler -- Set this to a class that implements
# RequestScheduler, which will schedule incoming client requests
# according to the specific policy. This is useful for multi-tenancy
# with a single Cassandra cluster.
# NOTE: This is specifically for requests from the client and does
# not affect inter node communication.
# org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler - No scheduling takes place
# org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.RoundRobinScheduler - Round robin of
# client requests to a node with a separate queue for each
# request_scheduler_id. The scheduler is further customized by
# request_scheduler_options as described below.
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler

# Scheduler Options vary based on the type of scheduler
# NoScheduler - Has no options
# RoundRobin
#  - throttle_limit -- The throttle_limit is the number of in-flight
#                      requests per client.  Requests beyond 
#                      that limit are queued up until
#                      running requests can complete.
#                      The value of 80 here is twice the number of
#                      concurrent_reads + concurrent_writes.
#  - default_weight -- default_weight is optional and allows for
#                      overriding the default which is 1.
#  - weights -- Weights are optional and will default to 1 or the
#               overridden default_weight. The weight translates into how
#               many requests are handled during each turn of the
#               RoundRobin, based on the scheduler id.
#
# request_scheduler_options:
#    throttle_limit: 80
#    default_weight: 5
#    weights:
#      Keyspace1: 1
#      Keyspace2: 5

# request_scheduler_id -- An identifer based on which to perform
# the request scheduling. Currently the only valid option is keyspace.
# request_scheduler_id: keyspace

# index_interval controls the sampling of entries from the primrary
# row index in terms of space versus time.  The larger the interval,
# the smaller and less effective the sampling will be.  In technicial
# terms, the interval coresponds to the number of index entries that
# are skipped between taking each sample.  All the sampled entries
# must fit in memory.  Generally, a value between 128 and 512 here
# coupled with a large key cache size on CFs results in the best trade
# offs.  This value is not often changed, however if you have many
# very small rows (many to an OS page), then increasing this will
# often lower memory usage without a impact on performance.
index_interval: 128

# Enable or disable inter-node encryption
# Default settings are TLS v1, RSA 1024-bit keys (it is imperative that
# users generate their own keys) TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA as the cipher
# suite for authentication, key exchange and encryption of the actual data transfers.
# NOTE: No custom encryption options are enabled at the moment
# The available internode options are : all, none, dc, rack
#
# If set to dc cassandra will encrypt the traffic between the DCs
# If set to rack cassandra will encrypt the traffic between the racks
#
# The passwords used in these options must match the passwords used when generating
# the keystore and truststore.  For instructions on generating these files, see:
# http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CreateKeystore
#
encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: resources/dse/conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: tomcat
    truststore: resources/dse/conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: tomcat
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
    # require_client_auth: false  [1]: https://github.com/pchalamet/cassandra-sharp/wiki/Having-troubles
```

Comment: you better ask this question in datastax forum www.datastax.com/support-forums/forum/datastax-enterprise

Comment: @Steve McMohan can you include your full cassanda.YAML file please?

Comment: I've included the full file in the answer section for reference and due to character limit in the already asked question

Comment: I trimmed some comments out of the file to include it in your question. Normally we don't ask for so much code, but for some reason, Lyuben wants it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I was thinking he is missing a line in his configuration, and he is (`native_transport_port`) Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @Lyuben there is a *remote* possibilty I accidentally removed the line, if it was near tge top. I tried to be extremely careful only to delete comments, though.

Comment: @Andrew Barber I don't think you did, in fact i think the missing line is the answer to the problem here (testing it now)

Comment: your seed is the localhost and listener and rpc address are your physical IP. Why this?

Answer (score 6):

Lyuben is correct, you're setting a Cassandra 1.2+ property on Cassandra 1.1.9.3.

http://www.datastax.com/doc-source/pdf/dse30.pdf - see the section 'Components'.

The property you are trying to set 'start_native_transport' is only available in Cassandra 1.2+. The latest Datastax Community Edition includes Cassandra 1.2.3 if that helps.

How do I know? I guess you were also trying to use the new Datastax CQL3 driver (https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/master/driver-core), see pre-requisites, Cassandra 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a mismatch between the Cassandra version you are running, and the configuration that you want implemented. The `hinted_handoff_throttle_delay_in_ms` option was removed in cassandra 1.2.x (you can find the option in the datastax documentation for [cassandra 1.1.x](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/configuration/node_configuration#cassandra-yaml) but [not 1.2.x](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/configuration/node_configuration#cassandra-yaml).

If you are running an earlier version of cassandra CQL is enabled by default (but you know this based on your question comments), however some of the settings in your config are of a older version of cassandra.

Also, another potential problem is that you are missing the `native_transport_port` although I tested [this](https://gist.github.com/lyubent/5228059) config on Datastax community 3.0, specifically cassandra v1.2.2 the server was happily running:

```
 INFO 15:15:17,242 Cassandra version: 1.2.2
 INFO 15:15:17,243 Thrift API version: 19.35.0
 INFO 15:15:17,243 CQL supported versions: 2.0.0,3.0.1 (default: 3.0.1)
 INFO 15:15:17,264 Loading persisted ring state
 INFO 15:15:17,266 Starting up server gossip
 ...
 INFO 15:15:17,661 Node /127.0.0.1 state jump to normal
 INFO 15:15:17,665 Startup completed! Now serving reads.
 INFO 15:15:17,709 Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042...
 INFO 15:15:17,721 Binding thrift service to /0.0.0.0:9160
 INFO 15:15:17,739 Using TFramedTransport with a max frame size of 15728640 bytes.
 INFO 15:15:17,745 Using synchronous/threadpool thrift server on 0.0.0.0 : 9160
 INFO 15:15:17,746 Listening for thrift clients...
```